# window.variable can't be accessed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a website where there is the text "game over" with the id "vid" and I want it to randomize the uppercase and lowercase every 300 - 400 milliseconds and to remain like that for 40 milliseconds before resetting back to lowercase.
This is the code I got now:  (My Javascript is not very good)

```js
setInterval(function() {
  window.smth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 300;
  var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
  elem.textContent = "game over";
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.textContent = elem.textContent.split('').map(function(v) {
      var chance = Math.round(Math.random());
      return v = chance ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase();
    }).join('');
  }, window.smth);
}, window.smth + 40);
```

```html
<div id="vid"></div>
```

Everything works fine except the last 2 lines ignore "window.smth". I tried different ways of setting "smth" but I couldn't find a way that loops with the other code and can be accessed everywhere I use it.

Comment: Don't use the `window` object as a global variable holder. Just assign a variable normally the times you want your interval to run, outside of the interval.

Comment: What actually is the problem here? Why do you think `window.smth` is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Because `window.smth` is set in the callback, it's `undefined` when setting the interval. Even if you define `smth` after the first time the callback is called, it is still not going to work because the `setInterval` function is only called once.

The way to create an interval like this is multiple timeouts; pseudocode:

```js
setTimeout(_ => {
  // do something

  setTimeout(..., otherTime) // you don't want to nest and nest and nest this, just create a function for this that's recursive
}, time)
```

Comment: If you nest and nest and nest, you won't do it an infinite amount of times, you'll **need** to use `setInterval()`

Comment: Nope, that's not true. What i said in the comments; you'd have to create a function for this and call that recursively

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `window.smith` inside your first timeout callback, but you're using it BEFORE the callback is actually called.
So `window.smith` at last row is actually still `undefined` at that time

Try moving `window.smth` definition out of first callback like this:

```
window.smth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 300;
setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
  elem.textContent = "game over";
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.textContent = elem.textContent.split('').map(function(v) {
      var chance = Math.round(Math.random());
      return v = chance ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase();
    }).join('');
  }, window.smth);
}, window.smth + 40);
```

Comment: That'll mean that `window.smth` is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Put `smth` out of the `setInterval()` and into another:

```js
var smth = 500;
setInterval(function() {smth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 300;}, 250);

setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
  elem.textContent = "game over";
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.textContent = elem.textContent.split('').map(function(v) {
      var chance = Math.round(Math.random());
      return v = chance ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase();
    }).join('');
  }, smth);
}, smth);
```

```html
<div id="vid"></div>
```